# Button clicker Google multiplayer iOS

Tags: xcode, google-play-services

when compilear the Google example I can't get the authorization to create a game room.
All is ok in the Google console. The constants file have my app Id. What's is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file Constants.h

> // Update the following value with your Client ID, // Refer
>   https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#d_gather_credentials_for_authentication_and_authorization
>   for more information //
>
> ## define CLIENT_ID @"REPLACE_ME"   //<----------------- HERE

And change

> change the Bundle Identifier from com.example.ButtonClicker to
>   something appropriate for your Provisioning Profile. (It will probably
>   look like com..ButtonClicker)